# Chrome store statistics

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, web-statistics

I'm building a funnel for our chrome extension using Google analytics.

When it comes to the chrome store stats at the beginning of the funnel, the data the developer's dashboard provides is limited (impressions & installations only).

I'm looking for data such as referrals to my extension page, the amount of people who clicked on the extension page but didn't install it (not impressions).

Can this data be found in the dashboard or GA? where? and if not, how can I otherwise track this?

Thank you very much!
Efrat

Answer (score 5):

You can add a Google Analytics ID to your projects from the Developer Dashboard. Create a new account in Analytics, click on "Edit" next to your project in the Chrome Developer Dashboard, and add the ID near the bottom of the page. (I'm not sure how new this feature is, but it is a little hard to find).

Inside Analytics, I have a goal set up for the URL `/track_install/detail/ext/free/{% my extension id %}`, which tracks installations. This shows the number of views without an install in the goal funnel. Referrals are available like any other Analytics page. GA is much more granular and updates in real time instead of once a day like the dashboard.