# Chrome Web Store traffic - how can I see a detailed split by traffic source?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to see from where traffic is coming to my Chrome Web Store extension?

I'd like to understand how many find the extension through:
- my own website
- searching on Chrome store
- searching on Google
- find it in a blog
etc.

This way I could draw similar conclusions that I can do in Google Analytics. For instance, understand which ways of marketing are working and which ones are not.

I found [Chrome store statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11242269/chrome-store-statistics) and https://developer.chrome.com/apps/analytics but it seems still fairly unclear if this is possible or how I should go about it.

Comment: I would love to know more about this too. All the resources except your first link are about page analytics inside the extension not about the web store. It is not too detailed but at least it confirms the possibility. I will look into it more tonight. If you get somewhere with it please share.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. All you need to do is specify an Analytics tracking ID on the extension's publishing page. No changes are needed for the extension.

Then your Analytics property will start receiving info on Web Store listing traffic, including traffic sources.

Old Dashboard:
[image: Old Dashboard]
New Dashboard:
[image: New Dashboard]

The explanatory link is somewhat misleading as it talks about embedding analytics into apps. For people landing on your store page, you don't need that.

When creating the Analytics property, specify it as a website and the URL as the Web Store listing URL. I don't think it matters though which exact URL you specify, as it still works with one of my properties mistakenly set to dashboard edit page.

Comment: Thank you for this, it really is pretty easy, still very strange that there is no documentation whatsoever about it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was better linked documentation at some point. I guess it was just lost in restructuring.

Comment: Okay, thanks again. Set it up before my previous comment and I can see where my users are coming from now! I don't know how I could live without this till now :)