# Can we track from where the user is coming to download my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, ads, chrome-web-store

We have recently launched chrome extension for our product. We want to run FB, Google and LinkedIn Ads for the same. The issue is how do we track if people our coming to download after seeing our ads.

Is there any way to check UTM source in the Chrome Admin webstore Dashboard?

Another workaround could be to use a bitly link and direct the customers to webstore page.

If you know of any other way please share that as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome Web Store traffic - how can I see a detailed split by traffic source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55492617/chrome-web-store-traffic-how-can-i-see-a-detailed-split-by-traffic-source)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the source param in utm_campaign to the store and it will be reported to GA.